# How to get reminders to throw in shared or public calendar Outlook 2003

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, microsoft-outlook-2003

Want to setup a calendar in the office that one of the departments can add items to and then receive reminders as you would in personal calendar. I have tried a couple approaches,
1. Setup a calendar in Public folder, add users, create appt, click reminder checkbox and I get this warning:
   "The reminder for "test" will not appear because the item in not in your Calendar or   tasksfolder...", I have tried moving calendar to different spots, but does not have any effect.

2. Tried sharing my personal calendar with another user and I get reminder, but the other user does not.

Checked that reminders are "checked" in Tools - options-other -advanced - reminder options.
I have poked around a little and it seems it may be a limitation of Outlook 2003. Are there options available to fix this, besides buying a pricey addon. Any free solutions out there I guess is my question?
thanks for your replies!

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to make this happen.  I have been looking for a decade.

Comment: that sucks, guess one more reason to think about upgrading...

Comment: Upgrading doesn't help.  It isn't present in any version of Outlook/Exchange.  Microsoft has been talking about eliminating Public folders for the last decade.  They basically ignore anything related to public folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zoredeache mentions in the comment, there is no built in function there are some third party tools that can be found by Google search.  I looked for documented "proof" from Microsoft that it does not exist, but on quick search did not find it.

**Edit**
Given the constraints and goals you have mentioned.  You should be able to meet your goal of sending reminders using outlook 2003, using delayed email delivery. You write an email to everyone who needs the reminder, then set the "Do not deliver before" time to what ever you want, click send, and your email arrives as the specified reminder time.

Reference 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/delay-or-schedule-sending-e-mail-messages-HP005242790.aspx

Comment: Public folders was just one of the ways I thought about doing it. Even if the functionality was there when I created an other calendar in my Inbox and then shared it, I would be happy... :) I though in one of the threads I read, this worked in later versions of Outlook, but that may just have been bogus info.

Comment: Why don't you just schedule something and invite everyone?

Comment: Thanks for the help folks, I'll do some tests on both ideas and see where it takes me!

Comment: As there really was only 4 people that use this calender, and they all work in close proximity, I just had one setup a weekly reminder in personal calender. The Public calender is just a list of items that need to be updated on a given date, so I would imagine that even the reminder will become moot at some point, and it will just become second nature for the staff to check weekly.